# How to merge a gejoson properties with an array based on the same key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two objects with same length and a common property `edge_id` on each Id. I would like to add to the second object to the properties of the first object.

I have a MapLibre map that I would like to add some properties coming from an API (the second object).

First object

```
 [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "edge_id": 67135,
            "color": "#f7fabf"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [ ]
        
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "edge_id": 15984,
            "color": "#fcd6a4"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [ ]
        }
    },
]
```

Second object

```
[
    {
        "edge_id": 67135,
        "name": "R12",
        "length": 0.14907826598895346,
        "speed": null,
        "lanes": null
    },
    {
        "edge_id": 15984,
        "name": "Pont de Sully",
        "length": 0.01577450403315043,
        "speed": 30,
        "lanes": 2
    },
]
```

I want the below output for `edge_id : 67135`:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "edge_id": 67135,
        "color": "#f7fabf",
        "name": "R12",
        "length": 0.14907826598895346,
        "speed": null,
        "lanes": null
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [ ]
    }
},
```

Comment: i dont understant what you want like result, could you refactor your question with the two object starting and what you want like final output

Comment: @Frenchy, the first example is the output I want to have

Answer (score 0):

I would first collect the second object's items by `edge_id` so that we can look them up in constant time later on:

```js
const secondObjectByEdgeId = secondObject.reduce(
  (o, x) => ({ ...o, [x.edge_id]: x }),
  {}
);
```

And then iterate over the first object's items, enhancing their `properties` field with what we just collected above:

```js
const merged = firstObject.map((x) => ({
  ...x,
  properties: {
    ...x.properties,
    ...secondObjectByEdgeId[x.properties.edge_id]
  }
}));
```

Note that the above approach will simply ignore any item in the second object whose `edge_id` is *not* present in the first object.

---

Same algorithm relying on side-effects:

```js
const secondObjectByEdgeId = secondObject.reduce(
  (o, x) => {
    o[x.edge_id] = x;
    return o;
  },
  {}
);

firstObject.forEach((x) => {
  Object.assign(x.properties, secondObjectByEdgeId[x.properties.edge_id]);
});
```

`firstObject` has now been updated directly.

Comment: @sp00n Lots of thanks. It's working with small objects but not on huge one because it's very slow

Comment: @aba2s Complexity wise, I'm not sure you'll find a better algorithm. What could help perhaps in your case is to rely on side-effects instead of recreating objects each time, if you want to give this a try?

Comment: @aba2s I've updated accordingly to provide an approach based on side-effects, it _might_ perform better, although we're stepping outside my JS expertise with this, so I won't able to explain precisely why one would perform better than the other (just FYI).